# Cannot make a screenshot using Print-key on Gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome, screenshot, troubleshooting

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME shell 3.10.4. Pressing the [Print]-key will cause the screen to shortly turn dark - as it seems to be custom on Ubuntu for capturing a screen.

But afterwards there is no screen shot available to be pasted on the clipboard.

Does somebody know how to repair or troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot should automatically save to the `~/Pictures` folder:
[image]

You can get the prompt to save or copy the screenshot (right) by using the 'Screenshot' dialogue *(search in the overview for `screenshot`, or run `gnome-screenshot --interactive`)*. This also enables you to include options such as whether to include the mouse pointer etc. [image]

You can also set in Keyboard settings what commands can be used for Screenshots - so you for instance to screenshot copy to clipboard by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> *(or whatever is set in the settings)*:
[image]

If you want to have the screenshot dialogue open, add you can add a custom keyboard shortcut to launch `gnome-screenshot --interactive` - I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>:

[image]